# Access value in Grails config file

Tags: arrays, grails, groovy, config

What am I doing wrong here?

In my config file I have this line:

```
payments.mail.partner = [
      some_partner: "partner@email.com",
      other_partner: "partner2@email.com"
]
```

In a service I'm trying to access the email address depending on the key. It seems like I should be able to just access it like this, where the partner parameter corresponds to the key in the config array.

```
def getPartnerEmail(partner) {
 String partnerEmailAddress = grailsApplication.config.payments.mail.partner[partner]
}
```

However this just returns a Groovy object. I tried converting it to a string but no luck. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not that it should matter in this case, but you usually want to put what version of Grails you're using.

Comment: it basically looks fine for me. Have you tried to debug your code in order to see what exactly you get? It is often very helpful to just do a `println partnerEmailAddress.dump()`...

Comment: This is what I get in the dump:

<java.lang.String@faed2eaa value=groovy.util.ConfigObject@2abf808d hash=-85119318 hash32=0>

Comment: try to dump other parts of your code... start with `grailsApplication` and work yourself towards `grailsApplication.config.payments.mail.partner`. Since you force your result to be a `String`, you dump doen't give you a good clue... If you dump `grailsApplication.config.payments.mail.partner[partner]` directly, you'll see the content of the `ConfigObject` you get.

Comment: btw: could it be that the config from above is enclosed in another config closure or that there are other config parts which may overwrite your config? Anyway - you'll see this if you dump the right part of your expression :-)